# How do you hide the "I Like It" and "Tags & Notes" buttons on a specific page?

Tags: css, tagging

How do you hide the "I Like It" and "Tags & Notes" buttons on a specific page?

I have a business requirement that these be removed on specific pages because they don't fit in with the purpose of the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove these on a specific page I added a content editor webpart with the simple CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
.ms-socialNotif-Container{display: none;}
</style>
```

As an added bonus you can remove the recycle bin and all site content section with:

```
.s4-specialNavLinkList{display: none;}
```